# How to get feature name while parallel execution in karate

Tags: karate

I want to store all feature names in a list for PASS & FAIL while parallel execution in Karate.

the purpose is, I want to log those feature execution details in TestRail(Test Management Tool) by calling another JavaClass while parallel execution.

Comment: karate outputs JSON files and the `Results` object can be used to get all data in 1.0 - read this also: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#retry-framework-experimental